# Pandas Dataframe filter results with Merge. Encoding Decoding Issues

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, character-encoding

I read tons of posts from our database for the last few days. with my limited skills in python and pandas and numpy, i am not sure if i found the answers that I desire. so would you please take a look at my situation, and see what i can do with it. and I am sorry about the chinese characters in the searching results.

I am currently writing some quant analysis for personal use. I retrieved a csv file via tushare-pro, which is a 3825-rows dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(stock_stats_ts.csv))
data1 = np.array(df1.loc[:,:])
```

returns

```
[[300826 'N测绘' '建筑工程' ... 41.16 16.85 40171.0]
 [2770 '科迪乳业' '乳制品' ... 21.05 4.38 47133.0]
 [2503 '搜于特' '服饰' ... 8.6 3.08 65664.0]
 ...
 [2260 '*ST德奥' '家用电器' ... 23.08 3.03 24704.0]
 [995 '*ST皇台' '白酒' ... 68.05 -35.24 10275.0]
 [939 '*ST凯迪' '新型电力' ... 10.79 -74.92 79373.0]]
```

and then I narrow it down to things i desire, such as code/name/esp/pb/roe

```
df2 = df1.loc[:,['code','name','esp','pb','npr']]
data2 = np.array(df1.loc[:,:])
```

returns

```
[[300826 'N测绘' 1.08 2.79 16.85]
 [2770 '科迪乳业' 0.03 2.13 4.38]
 [2503 '搜于特' 0.098 2.17 3.08]
 ...
 [2260 '*ST德奥' 0.034 0.0 3.03]
 [995 '*ST皇台' -0.079 0.0 -35.24]
 [939 '*ST凯迪' -0.362 0.0 -74.92]]
```

and I also have a list of stock names which i desire from previous session

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(candidates.csv))
data3 = np.array(df3.loc[:,['candidates']])
```

returns

```
[['维维股份']
 ['ST正源']
 ['美克家居']
 ['*ST金山']
 ['大有能源']
 ['好当家']
 ['贵州茅台']
 ['通策医疗']
 ['杭州解百']
 ['耀皮玻璃']
 ['梅花生物']
 ['金牌厨柜']
 ['继峰股份']
 ['胜利股份']
 ['渝 开 发']
 ['云南白药']
 ['中原环保']
 ['兴蓉环境']
 ['华闻集团']
 ['粤 水 电']
 ['濮耐股份']
 ['*ST东南']
 ['洪涛股份']
 ['达实智能']
 ['千红制药']
 ['闽发铝业']
 ['史丹利']
 ['加加食品']
 ['张家港行']
 ['国联水产']]
```

What i am sure of is that my candidates are in df2[name] columns for sure, and then, with what lines of codes so that I can filter my df2 based on the results i have from df3?

Thanks to chief @Rexhil Regmi and @nimrodm, my question worked perfectly with `pd.merge`. However, all those chinese characters in are encoding in 'gbk' which is unreadable with MS Excel. Any hints to change them into 'utf8'?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a merge for this problem of yours.

```
new_df = df3.merge(df1, left_on='candidate', right_on='name', how='left')
```

This should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: I will look into pd.dataframe more as I progress with my quantitative analysis. Thank you Chief!

Comment: I have another thing popped up as I went along with the coding, My [code] column is encoded with 'gbk', so when i open with excel (decoded with utf8), names are in geeburish...any recommendations, chief?

Comment: This is beautiful! Solved my problem too!

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to join the two tables (similar to SQL JOIN). Pandas `merge` performs an inner join meaning you select only rows that have a matching entry in the candidates data frame.

So, for example `result.csv` is

```
name,value
first,10
second,20
third,30
```

And `selected.csv` is

```
candidates
first
third
```

Read both of these as DataFrames (no need to convert to a numpy array):

```
data = pd.read_csv('result.csv')
selected = pd.read_csv('selected.csv')
```

And join the two (the `how` parameter is optional since `inner` is the default value for `merge`)

```
data.merge(selected, how='inner', left_on='name',right_on='candidates')

    name  value candidates
0  first     10      first
1  third     30      third
```

This joins the two DataFrames looking for rows where the value of data[j,'name'] == data[k, 'candidates']

#### Another option

Another approach is to directly select lines where `name` (in my example) is in a given list:

```
data[data['name'].isin(selected['candidates'])]    

    name  value 
0  first     10
2  third     30
```

This is probably inefficient unless, perhaps, the candidates list is very short.

Comment: I will look into pd.dataframe more as I progress with my quantitative analysis. Thank you Chief!

Comment: I have another thing popped up as I went along with the coding, My [name] column is encoded with 'gbk', so when i open with excel (decoded with utf8), names are in geeburish...any recommendations, chief?

Comment: @pepCoder: Do actually instruct Excel to use utf8? Excel's default is utf-16LE. So if you generate a CSV (or even better for Excel - a tab separated values files) with UTF16-LE encoding, excel will read it perfectly. Try this: `r.to_csv('output.tsv', sep='\t',encoding='utf-16le')`